# Sublime Text Ctrl + B wont show output (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

**Here is my code:**

```
var message = "Hello World";
console.log(message);
```

**Here is the error after Ctrl + B:**

```
/home/kazak/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/javaScr.js: line 1: var: command not found
/home/kazak/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/javaScr.js: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `message'
/home/kazak/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/javaScr.js: line 2: `console.log(message);'
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 2]
[cmd: ['/bin/bash', '/home/kazak/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/javaScr.js']]
[dir: /home/kazak/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]
```

Comment: What build system are you using?

Comment: Looks like a Linux distro to me.
@Almaz, Have you set your build system to JavaScript?

Comment: My build system is: 'ShellScript'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you have installed `python` and `node`.

Open `sublime text` > `Tools` > `Build System` > `New Build System` > copy and paste `Python Build System` code, change "cmd" path with your python location > press `ctrl+s` save the build file in default location with whatever file name you want but make sure the file extension is `.sublime-build`.

Do the same thing for javascript build system and change "cmd" path to your node location.

Python Build System Code

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/path/to/your/python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    // if you want to see the execution information set "quiet":false
    "quiet": true,
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

JavaScript Build System Code

```
{   
    "cmd": ["/usr/path/to/your/node", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "quiet": true,
    "selector": "source.js"
}
```

After you created two build system, now again open `sublime text` > `Tools` > `Build System` > `Automatic`

Open your `javascript` or `python` file press `ctrl+b` select your build system, you're ready to rock!

Comment: Glad to hear that :).